# Unit testing streamed filed download with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I have a function that takes an array of URLs to images, loops through them and downloads them to a local directory written in typescript. I am trying write a unit test for the function in Jest and running into issue with mocking some parts of it. In the code below, `filepath` is the location the file is being written to and `url` is the URL of the current image.

```js
const finished = promisify(stream.finished);
const writer = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);

axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: url,
    responseType: 'stream'  // Make the response a stream
}).then(async (response) => {
    response.data.pipe(writer);  // Send the response stream to the writable file stream
    await finished(writer);  // Watch the stream for being finished/any errors
}).catch(error => {
    console.error('Image Download');
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

How would you properly mock the axios stream, the fs.createWriteStream, and the stream.finished functions? I am already using `axios-mock-adapter` for mocking axios in other unit tests where the code is just getting a response from an API and not streaming a file.